# v-data-table customs pagination button

Tags: vuetify.js

I had a v-data-tabel wants use pagaination control button and place to somewhere in the page.  Here is a simplified code.

My question is which property I should change ?  I try "footerProps:{'page-options':20}",  but it is not functioned.  Thank you very much !

I am using vuetify 2.4.6

```
<v-app>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="item"
      item-key="id"
      :footer-props="footerProps"
      hide-default-footer
      >
      <template v-slot:top="{ pagination, options, updateOptions }">
       <v-toolbar color="blue-grey lighten-5">
          <v-card class="ma-0 pa-0 ">
              <v-row>
                <v-col>
                  <v-list-item three-line>
                      <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-subtitle class="text-wrap">page : {{pagination.page}} of {{pagination.pageCount}} ({{options.itemsPerPage}})</v-list-item-subtitle>
                          <v-list-item-subtitle class="text-wrap">record : {{pagination.pageStart}}-{{pagination.pageStop}} of
                          {{pagination.itemsLength}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
                      </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
               </v-col>
               <v-col>
                  <v-btn  @click="advance">advance</v-btn>  
                  <v-btn @click="backward">back</v-btn>
                </v-col>
             </v-row>
           </v-card>
          </v-toolbar>
        ....
      </template>
   </v-data-table>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for `v-pagination` component. You can place it anywhere on your page and sync it with your `v-data-table`. Check [v-pagination](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/) for more info and the [external pagination](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-pagination) example on Vuetify's documentation page.